# What happen if thread crashes, which is better thread or process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix

I am writing a server application with one connection at a time, I receive a TCP request which has symbol names of function and name of shared libraray.

My server needs to load the shared library using the `dlsym` system call and call the function using symbol name received.

Right now loading the shared lib and executing the function I am doing in separate thread. My doubt is when thread crashed due to segmentation fault or any signals will my process gets affected ?

Which one is better whether to run in separate thread or process.

Please ask me question If my question is not clear.

Comment: The thread is better.

Comment: Why not simply test  it?

Comment: Add `int tmpi = 0; tmpi /= tmpi;` to one of your processes' threads and see what happens.

Comment: @Martin James . If threads are better can you please let me know how can I handle signal in multithread situations. since after signal arose from the kernel I don't have proper control on my program and behaviour is strange

Comment: @alk : I am trying the same as you mentioned but finding strange behaviour

Comment: "*finding strange behaviour*" is a somewhat "*strange*" trouble report.

Answer (score 10):

A crash in a thread takes down the whole process. And you probably wouldn't want it any other way since a crash signal (like SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGABRT) means that you lost control over the behavior of the process and anything could have happened to its memory.

So if you want to isolate things, spawning separate processes is definitely better. Of course, if someone can make your process crash it's pretty close to them owning your computer anyway. I sure hope that you don't intend to expose this to untrusted users.

Comment: Thanks @Art for you information. In my scenario I am testing the library functionalities , so there are more chances of signal faults occurs in library. Can you please clarify about you last sentence " I sure hope that you don't intend to expose this to untrusted users"

Comment: If you expose something like this to untrusted users they can take over the machine that runs this service in seconds. It's a security nightmare.